# How do I start the dts transfer program?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, dts

I am not that familiar with SQL Server data transfer and I am trying to setup a nightly database transfer for certain tables from SQL Server 2000 to SQL server 2008.  I am reading up on DTS, but I dont know how to get it started.  Is it possible to have a few steps that would point me in the right direction at least?

**EDIT**

Issue:  How do I copy a Person Table in Personal Database(SQL 2000) to Person Table in  Personal Database(SQL 2008) nightly?

Comment: You aren't sure how to execute a step in the package, the whole package, or schedule the package?

Comment: not sure how to execute a step and schedule the package I guess.  My task option has import and export, but I would like to set up a schedule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can schedule a DTS by creating SQL Server agent job, and adding the DTS execution as a scheduled task.

By your use of the term 'DTS' I'm inferring that you are using the SQL Server 2000 tool. Later versions of SQL have SSIS (SQL Server Itegrated Services), which might be a better option for you.

With this you'll need to

1. Add a data flow task
2. Drill down into the data flow task.
3. Add two database connections, your 2000 and 2008 databases
4. Add a data source and destination.
5. Connect the two.

Give it a shot.

Comment: Create new project. From toolbox, drag 'Data flow Task' onto the canvas. They'll be tons of tutorials around. Suggest you do a few searches.